# Magento Error: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

```
Error log record number: 445792780098

Log:
a:4:{i:0;s:46:"SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'";i:1;s:3072:"#0 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) #4 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array) #5 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8') #6 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) #7 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write') #8 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') #9
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter() #10 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter() #11 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions() #12 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions() #13 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config') #14 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config') #15 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit() #16 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache() #17 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() #18 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #19 
/home/geschenk/domains/geschenkengenieten.nl/public_html/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store') #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I had transfer via Directadmin
Can anyone please figure out the problem?

Comment: Well the First Line Says it All. "Unknown database 'test'". Meaning, the MySQL Host your website is connecting to does not have a database called "test". Check out your local.xml file in /app/etc/ for this line "<dbname><![CDATA[test]]></dbname>". You probably have two options, either copy your "test" database to the server (not likely) or correct the "test" dbname in your local.xml file. If your local.xml file is fine, figure out if you have any custom scripts or extensions that connect to this "test" MySQL Database. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a database connectivity issue. Please check the database credentials (database name. username and password) in your local.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Please uncomment these

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in index.php ! As you get errors in your browser you are probably using wrong database credentials or have wrong file permissions.